# Groupby Ploting - give each plot title/name

Tags: python, geopandas, matplotlib, pandas

I have used this code to group by the continents and then plotted using geopandas. I would like to set the plot title for each continent. I would have liked also to draw the continents side by side.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

continent = world.groupby('continent')
continent.plot()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to represent the continents side by side, you have to create subplots on the same fig. To do so, you can iterate through your group of continents. Here is an example:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
continent = world.groupby('continent')

plt.figure()

# Iterate through continents

for i, (continent_name, continent_gdf) in enumerate(continent):
    # create subplot axes in a 3x3 grid
    ax = plt.subplot(3, 3, i + 1) # nrows, ncols, axes position
    # plot the continent on these axes
    continent_gdf.plot(ax=ax)
    # set the title
    ax.set_title(continent_name)
    # set the aspect
    # adjustable datalim ensure that the plots have the same axes size
    ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='datalim')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

yields

[image: continents]

Comment: Very nice! How can I adjust the figsize?

Comment: With the figsize keyword argument. See https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figure.html

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've played around with it but I don't get where exactly I have to position `figsize(x,y)`

Comment: If I add `plt.figsize(10,5)` behind the for loop I receive the following error: `AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'figsize'`

Comment: Neither can I place it within `ax = plt.subplot()`

Comment: Has the figsize problem been solved?